# Question on how to approach measurability questions for real valued functions

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

My question is regarding the following Proposition:

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function. If the set $C$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f^{-1}(C) \in \mathcal{A}$.

My question is about the interpretation of this proposition.
If I did understand that Proposition correctly, then this would be very useful when trying to show that for example a function is measurable.
Here is an example of how I think this should work:

Consider $f(x)=|sin(x)|$.
Since $|.|$ and $\sin$ are continuous, they are Borel measurable.
Consider $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$,then $f^{-1}((a,\infty)) \in \mathcal{A}$ since $(a,\infty) \in \mathcal{B}$.

Is my assumption about the use of the Proposition correct? And, does this work like in the example I provided?